# How use component react created with enzyme example mocha in browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, enzyme

Can i use https://github.com/lelandrichardson/enzyme-example-mocha/blob/master/src/Foo.js in web browser?

I try but, babel create js with undefined words.

Example code generated:
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
    value: true
});

Message:  ReferenceError: exports is not defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before responding yes or no, quick reminder :

- React : Library to create UI
- Enzyme : Library to test React component
- Mocha : Test Framework to run test on Node.js. As you can see to run test on the browser, you need a module like `jsdom` which create a [DOM](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/enzyme-example-mocha/blob/master/test/.setup.js#L3) to run tests.
- Babel : Tool to compile javascript code

The aim of this repository is to give you an example on how to test a React component with Enzyme and Mocha. That's all.

So by using this respository without modifications, the answer is **no** because the package contains just a `Foo` component and this component is not rendered in a DOM.

So to see the result in a browser, you need to render this component in a DOM with `react-dom`.

Example:
**bundle.js** :

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Foo} from './src/Foo';

render(
  <div>
    <Foo/>
  </div>
  ,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**index.html** :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Foo component</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"/>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

But you will also need [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io) to bundle all your files and dependencies.
I recommend you to read a [complete article](https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack) to understand the complete process about how to compile a React app. It will also introduce you **Webpack** an amazing tool to bundle your javascript app.

Comment: in my application i trying same case of enzyme example, that's it, i need webpack ... with browserify + babelify not worked

Comment: In some days, I'm gonna publish a startkit on GitHub with a complete example (webpack, babel - and a test part with karma, enzyme). [Follow me](https://github.com/LouisBarranqueiro) to be notified :)